# center expanded div with media screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying align the expanded card div to the center, when the media screen max-width 992px/768px

At the moment when i expand the div the expanded div is not centered.

What flex property should i use here? if so,how?

Here a demo of how the grid layout shifts and the cards next to the expanded div misaligned.

You will need to view in full window / resize the window to see it change size

```js
var $cell = $('.card');

//open and close card when clicked on card
$cell.find('.js-expander').click(function() {

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');

  if ($thisCell.hasClass('is-collapsed')) {
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-inactive');
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-expanded');
    
    if ($cell.not($thisCell).hasClass('is-inactive')) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      $cell.not($thisCell).addClass('is-inactive');
    }

  } else {
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');
  }
});

//close card when click on cross
$cell.find('.js-collapser').click(function() {

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');

  $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
  $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');

});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eceef1;
  font-family: "Slabo 27px", serif;
  color: #333a45;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 5em auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.header {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.header__title {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
.header__subtitle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #949fb0;
  font-family: "Yesteryear", cursive;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.cards {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;

  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  margin: 15px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 30px);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.card:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
.card__inner {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #949fb0;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.card__inner:after {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.card__inner .fa {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}
.card__expander {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #333a45;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.card__expander .fa {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card__expander .fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.card.is-collapsed .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
}
.card.is-collapsed .card__expander {
  max-height: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #333a45;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner .fa:before {
  content: "";
}
.card.is-expanded .card__expander {
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-top: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.card.is-expanded:hover .card__inner {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.card.is-inactive .card__inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.card.is-inactive:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #949fb0;
  transform: scale(1);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {

  .card__expander {
    width: 250%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card__expander {
    width: 150%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Expanding Card Grid With Flexbox</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px|Yesteryear'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="header__title">Expanding Card Grid</h1>
    <h2 class="header__subtitle">with Flexbox</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="cards">

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult because each `card_expander` is linked to its parent `card` and its position depends on it. If you center `card_expander`, it will be centered relative to its parent and not to the page.

[image]

[image]

One solution would be to adjust the position of `each card_expander`.

```js
var $cell = $('.card');

//open and close card when clicked on card
$cell.find('.js-expander').click(function() {

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');

  if ($thisCell.hasClass('is-collapsed')) {
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-inactive');
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-expanded');
    
    if ($cell.not($thisCell).hasClass('is-inactive')) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      $cell.not($thisCell).addClass('is-inactive');
    }

  } else {
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');
  }
});

//close card when click on cross
$cell.find('.js-collapser').click(function() {

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');

  $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
  $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');

});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eceef1;
  font-family: "Slabo 27px", serif;
  color: #333a45;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 5em auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.header {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.header__title {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
.header__subtitle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #949fb0;
  font-family: "Yesteryear", cursive;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.cards {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;

  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  margin: 15px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

  /* ---------- HERE ---------- */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 30px);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.card:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
.card__inner {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #949fb0;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.card__inner:after {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.card__inner .fa {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}
.card__expander {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #333a45;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* ---------- HERE ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .card:nth-child(odd) .card__expander {
    align-self: start;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 75px);
  }
  .card:nth-child(even) .card__expander {
    align-self: end;
    margin-right: calc(50% - 75px);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
  .card:nth-child(1) .card__expander {
    align-self: start;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 45px);
  }
  .card:nth-child(3) .card__expander {
    align-self: end;
    margin-right: calc(50% - 45px);
  }
  .card:nth-child(even) .card__expander {
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
/* -------------------------- */

.card__expander .fa {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card__expander .fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.card.is-collapsed .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
}
.card.is-collapsed .card__expander {
  max-height: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #333a45;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner .fa:before {
  content: "";
}
.card.is-expanded .card__expander {
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-top: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.card.is-expanded:hover .card__inner {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.card.is-inactive .card__inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.card.is-inactive:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #949fb0;
  transform: scale(1);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {

  .card__expander {
    width: 250%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card__expander {
    width: 150%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Expanding Card Grid With Flexbox</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px|Yesteryear'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="header__title">Expanding Card Grid</h1>
    <h2 class="header__subtitle">with Flexbox</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="cards">

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, that still does not center each expanded div, if i click on the first and 3rd on they are on the edge of page

Comment: You can't center the first and 3rd. See my 2nd screenshot.

Comment: You can try with `position: absolute` , `transform: translate (-50%, -50%);` etc. But it will be complicated and the result not perfect. Good luck.

Comment: so not even with javascript?

Comment: See my edited answer. I combined `align-self` and `margin` to center `card__expander`.

Comment: Thankyou i think thats it, i have been trying to do this with javascript

Comment: i did find one problem, if you remove all cards and only have 2 showing it does not seem to center